# Playwright handling authentication with multiple workers

Tags: authentication, playwright

Running into a small problem, or maybe a question about the best way to handle this. Playwright touches on authentication some here: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth

Currently im testing against a pretty old ASP.net app that uses a microservice architecture. Authenticating via API isn't really possible, however I am able to save the storage state/cookies as shown in the "Basic" example and stay logged in.

However most tests would probably be altering server-side state via doing basic CRUD requests via forms/etc...

In this case I do not have multiple accounts that can be used, and even if I did wouldn't I need an `n` amount of accounts dependent on the amount of workers? (From my understanding there is one worker per test file correct?)

What pitfalls do I need to be careful of here then? I know I want to use the storage state to prevent multiple logins...but maybe it's something that makes sense to do once per test file and not once per project? (So workers aren't stepping over each other with server-side data manipulation?)

If so Im assuming I would need to do a single `beforeAll()` or Fixture that logs in-->saves the state--> and then I can somehow load the state in the `beforeEach()`. Or is the proper way to really go is to set up an account for each test?

I imagine I could do it per test via `test.use` but surely there is a better way to do this per file. Or just general best practices to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: Ideally you would have one account per worker, and none could step over each other’s toes. But it sounds like you can only have one account? In that case, logging in multiple times wouldn’t do anything if you’re still using the same account with the same system/environment.

Comment: Where is the code? What you have tried so far? Somebody would be  able to help you faster  if you share some minimal reproducible example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example